# How to disable auto import from specific files in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-import

Is there any way to tell vscode to not autoimport from specific files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. VS Code will pick up auto imports from all files in your [`jsconfig`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) or [`tsconfig`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) project.

If the file should not be part of your project, you can exclude it using the `excludes` or `includes` / `files` configuration option in the jsconfig or tsconfig

Comment: Have you got a source for this? I can not reliably exclude using this technique.

Comment: Do you have a jsconfig or tsconfig?

Comment: I have a tsconfig.

Comment: See this repo: https://github.com/dwjohnston/import-from-parent-issue/tree/tsconfig (note tsconfig branch) 
 go to `src/foo/fooFile.ts` and note that it still wants to import from the `src/index.ts` file, even though that it is excluded

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

VSCode now supports this natively, if your project uses TypeScript 4.8+.

Just search for "auto import" in your settings menu, or use the `typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns` key in your json.

[image]