# How can I exclude an ambient module declaration like node:test from VS Code's auto import suggestions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vitest, node-test-runner

I'm aware of the VS Code setting named `typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns` ([ref](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8-rc/#exclude-specific-files-from-auto-imports)), and my local VS Code is using a recent TypeScript version which support that setting:

[image]

Yet I'm not able to prevent VS Code from suggesting to import members from `node:test` module when writing my test files. For the records I'm using `vitest` as a test runner, which has typical function names clashing with `node:test` ones (`describe`, `beforeEach`, `it`).

I tried the following setting, with no luck:

```json
"typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": ["node:test"],
```

Of course `node-test` is not an npm package, so the classic example using `"**/node_modules/...some package name..."` does not apply here.

Did anyone come into this already?

Comment: potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/47796545/11107541, but I think it's a bit debatable, since this question has the different angle of being about a TypeScript _module_ and not about a file.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update: I was wrong(ish)

It seems you *can*. For example, to prevent suggestions from things in `node:test`, you can exclude the file(s) that define the module `"typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns": ["node/test.d.ts"]` in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson) (user or workspace, etc.). You were close with trying to use `node:test`, but `typescript.preferences.autoImportFileExcludePatterns` works with file paths and not TypeScript module names. The pattern `node/test.d.ts` will match the file that the `@types/node` defines the `node:test` module in. Caveat: This may only work nicely if the module is the only module defined in the files that define it. Otherwise, you may exclude modules that are defined in the same files. Though I was quite surprised to see that the file exclusion would work on type definition files that are triple-slash-referenced by an index type definition file.

#### Old (partially wrong) answer

VS Code added a feature to remember suggestion selections (see [Remember suggestion selections #22839](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22839)). You can see [the related commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e1131e3ef3c22f2d447d27e612daac1ce3678946) that completed the issue, and [this related file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/browser/suggestMemory.ts). This is to say- if you set the VS Code setting named `editor.suggestSelection` to either `"recentlyUsed"` or `"recentlyUsedByPrefix"`, I think you could get a nice workaround for what you want by just selecting the suggestion you want a couple times.

To get better than that (and actually exclude a specific ambient module declaration from auto import suggestions), I don't think this is easily possible. `node:test` is an ambient module declaration in `node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts`, which is referenced in `.node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts` by a `/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />`, and that index.d.ts file is made part of [module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) by virtue of being specified in the node module's package.json with `"types": "index.d.ts"`. I'm not aware of a feature to exclude module declarations from auto imports, and you don't want to [augment the module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)- you want to make it as if it didn't exist for IntelliSense purposes.

What you could try to do is make your own modified copy of the `@types/node` package where you edit that index.d.ts file to remove the line that does `/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />`.

There is a "nuclear" VS Code setting called `typescript.preferences.includePackageJsonAutoImports`, which I don't think is what you want- using it to disable the `node:test` import suggestion would also disable the import for the vitest module you want to import.

---

You may also be interested to read

- [VS Code TypeScript auto import suggestion priority](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63251182/11107541)
- [Delete a specific Intellisense suggestion in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58049533/11107541)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76938845/11107541

Comment: thanks. I checked if I was already using that `editor.suggestSelection` and I wasn't. Will try with that.