# VS Code how to always use a specific library for a function name

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use `redux-saga` library in my TypeScript project which has a `call` function exported, but I also have a lot of dependencies with a `call` export installed.
So if I write `yield* call(...)`, VS Code gives quite a lot of suggestions for the `call` function:

[image: a lot of imports]

And I always use `redux-saga` for the `call` import, but searching it through so many suggestions is really an inconvenience.
Is there a way to set up VS Code so it always suggests `redux-saga` first?

Comment: related?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76788709/11107541

Comment: are you actually depending upon all those packages directly (`dependencies` in package.json)? this could just be a side-effect of NPM's way of laying out installed transitive dependencies. does this happen if you nuke `node_modules` and then switch to using pnpm instead?

Comment: Most of these packages are not listed in the `dependencies`, but it's not that easy to move from `npn` to `pnpn` in our project, because our CI depends on it

Comment: please for the sake of debugging the problem, just test pnpm locally to see if there's a change in behaviour

Comment: I was a little bit mistaken. Most of these packages are not in `dependencies`, but in `dev-dependencies`, so switching to `pnpm` doesn't help here

Comment: why? the distinction between dependencies or devdependencies doesn't change the installation structure. the choice of package manager can. that's why I keep asking you to try pnpm.

Comment: I tried and it didn't help

Comment: I ran `rm -rf ./node_modules` and then `pnpm i`, and also relaunched VS Code

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, VS Code doesn't support built-in feature to prioritize specific libraries for autocompletion.
But here are some methods that I am using in my development.

**Method 1: Use Alias**

You can use alias when you import the function.

```
import { call as sagaCall } from 'redux-saga/effects';
```

You can use sagaCall in your code.

**Method 2: Custom Snippets**

You can create custom snippets in VS Code for frequently used code patterns.
To create a custom snippet:

1. Go to Configure User Snippets

   -Code/Preferences/Configure User Snippets on macOS

   -File/Preferences/Configure User Snippets on Windows.
2. Select typescript.json or the scope for which you want to create the snippet.
3. Add a new snippet:
   [Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuq9V.png)

Hope this can help you!!!