# How to prevent log from global async module suggestion in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, logging, autocomplete

How do I prevent this async suggestion when I type "log"?
I only want to get the console.log suggestion.

Looks like the async module is installed by default with vs code in this directory:
"C:/Users/Benny/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/5.3/node_modules/@types/async/index"

[image]

Comment: this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791396/11107541. but first I need more info to know if it really is. does your project have a package.json? have you listed the `async` package as a dependency of your package there? or do you have [automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_typings-and-automatic-type-acquisition) enabled and that's how you're getting this? have you touched the `typescript.tsdk` VS Code setting?

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/q/47796545/11107541. but again, more info fist please.